# Navigating back to main ViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated dilemma

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uiviewcontroller

I have 2 ViewControllers directly connected with a push segue. I am navigating from first to second view controller by calling `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segueIdentifier" sender:sender]`. On the second one I have an IBAction method that is bound to a "Done" button. Pressing that button should basically cause the first view controller to be displayed (sort of a back button). I managed to do that with:

```
NSArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
[self.navigationController popToViewController:[viewControllers
objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];
```

I did try to achieve the same effect by using:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

No matter what I tried though this didn't do the job. I am trying to understand what exactly am I missing but I can't figure it out. Does dismissViewControllerAnimated method work only with Modal segues ( this is the only thing that came to mind ).

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes,

```
- (void)dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)flag completion:(void (^)(void))completion
```

is when a UIViewController is displayed modally.

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

should do what you are seeking.

So basically, in your second VC:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You will save you a lot of trouble if you read the UIViewController and UINavigationController  references. Twice ;)

Comment: I am currently doing that. Third time. Thank you for your answer

Comment: I had to read them a few times before understanding the whole picture. practice makes perfect ;)