# dismissViewController is not working properly

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

Below is a hierarchy of my navigation controller

```
MainViewController
      |
      |
      DetailViewController
```

Then I do the following on DetailViewController

```
[self presentViewController:reminderController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

After navigating to ReminderViewController, at some points I do

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, it brings me back to MainViewController instead of DetailViewController

That is weird. Any thoughts about this issue...

EDITED :

The reason I do `presentViewController: reminderController animated: completion:` on DetailViewController because reminderController is used to send a reminder. Just like goole app or other apps, when sending sth , we are using presentViewController.

Comment: why aren't you using push and pop viewcontrollers ??

Comment: How do you present DetailViewController from MainViewController?

Comment: @X-Factor+@c.cam : see OP. I have just edited

Comment: Thats why i told you not to do dismissviewcontrolleranimated, instead use pushviewcontroller and popviewcontroller.

Comment: @user1066524 I think that was meant to be directed @ttran?

Comment: @ttran: What exactly is the effect you are going for?? do you want it to pop out? do you want it to be a child window? do you want it to completely switch over to a new view?

Comment: if you are doing a reminder, you could always just do an alert view instead. but if you really want to do presentViewController you have to remember to dismiss it from within the same controller that you presented it in. I have had this problem MANY times working on ios. that's why i prefer to use either alert,  push, or pop unless I am presenting and dismissing within the same viewcontroller.

Comment: Let me see if I understand your setup. MainViewController is embedded in a navigation controller, and you use a push to go to DetailViewController. Then from that controller, you use presentViewController: to go to reminderController. At some point in reminderController, you use dismissViewController: to dismiss yourself, but it goes back to MainViewController instead of DetailViewController? Is that correct. This should work. Do you have any other segues or anything in your storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar :that is the way I am setting up the views al together...

Comment: hmmm... that should work then. There must be something wrong in the setup somewhere. Can you describe what you did in the storyboard?

Comment: @rdelmar: it is hard to describe at here because the hierarchy is complicated than. You are rite sth wrong internally and I am debugging it now. Thanks rdelmar

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample of the documentation regarding the `UIViewController` class:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the presented view controller itself, it automatically forwards the message to the presenting view controller.
>
> If you present several view controllers in succession, thus building a stack of presented view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

Thus, I think you should first use a segue to push your `DetailViewController`, and then present the `reminderController` modally, which you'll be later able to dismiss using `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` without dismissing `DetailViewController`.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `dismissViewController:animated:` use

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

`dismissViewController:animated` removes all the `UIViewController`s in it.

You will save you a lot of trouble if you read the UIViewController and UINavigationController references. Twice ;)

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375191/navigating-back-to-main-viewcontroller-dismissviewcontrolleranimated-dilemma) for more details.

Comment: you can not use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];` regarding to OP because I did used `presentViewController: reminderController animated: completion:` on DetailViewController.

Comment: This is incorrect. If you present a view controller (modally), then you use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: to dismiss it. Something else must be going on with the OP's project.

Comment: @rdelmar : sorry, iam confused.. why I am incorrect. the OP is using modal to present a view.

Comment: @ttran, my comment is addressed to X-Factor, not you.